# cannot return multiple value from do in background to post execute

Tags: java, android, return-value

Any idea regarding return multiple value in this situation? I want to obtain name, username and age at post execute method

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
try{
    URL url = new URL (strUrl);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.connect();

    //get response from server
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String value = bf.readLine();


    String json = value;
    JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(json);
    JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("Data");
    JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(parentArray.length()-1);

    String name = finalObject.getString("NAME");
    String username = finalObject.getString("USERNAME");
    String age = finalObject.getString("AGE");

    return name,username,age; //this part basically dont works

}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: append three string with # or other sign and pass it

Comment: Another option is to make a custom object to hold these values and return the object

Comment: @Denny any example?

Comment: @DivyeshPatel could you write me a simple one right here? I have no idea at all

Comment: Why don't you just pass the json string into post execute method and then parse that json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Model class like this..

```
public class Model {
    private String username,name,age;

    public Model(String username, String name, String age) {
        this.username = username;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

and use this for List and modify your `doInBackground()` method...

```
protected Model doInBackground(String... params) {
   try{
        URL url = new URL (strUrl);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.connect();

        //get response from server
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String value = bf.readLine();
        String json = value;
        JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("Data");
        JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(parentArray.length()-1);

        String name = finalObject.getString("NAME");
        String username = finalObject.getString("USERNAME");
        String age = finalObject.getString("AGE");

        return new Model(username,name,age);

       }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
       }
 }
```

and `onPostExecute()` use this

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Model m) {
    super.onPostExecute(m);
    String name=m.getName(); 
    String age=m.getAge(); 
    String username=m.getUsername(); 
}
```

Comment: Why make them public or create a model class? when you can simply make an array of ArrayList of string and pass that to post execute

Comment: @AwaisMajeed yea he can do that also.. this is one possible solution..also model class are good for reuse multiple times for same type of data

Answer (score 1):

You can directly send **value** From

```
String value = bf.readLine();
```

And in onPostExecute(), you can parse that **Json**.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
try{
    URL url = new URL (strUrl);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.connect();

    //get response from server
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String value = bf.readLine();


    String json = value;
    JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(json);
    JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("Data");
    JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(parentArray.length()-1);

    String name = finalObject.getString("NAME");
    String username = finalObject.getString("USERNAME");
    String age = finalObject.getString("AGE");

    return name+","+username+","+age;

}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    String[] array = s.split(",");
    String name = array[0];
    String username = array[1];
    String age = array[2];


 }
```

Comment: Why make them public or create a model class? when you can simply make an array of ArrayList of string and pass that to post execute

Comment: @AwaisMajeed "_Simple an array of arraylist of string_", why would you need an array of arraylist of string? An array of String would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
        String name="1";
        String username="b";
        String age="mn";

        String fullValue=name+"#"+username+"#"+age;
        return fullValue;
```

Now in OnpostExecute:

```
    String[] gn=fullValue.split("#");
    for (int i=0;i<gn.length;i++){
        Log.e("values",gn[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**
Append the results to one string with a delimiter and split them later
`return name + "~" + username + "~" + age;`
To split them:
`String[] seperated = YOURSTRING.Split("~");` and get the values with `seperated[0], seperated[1] and seperated[2]`

**Option 2:**
Make a class

```
public class User {
String name, username, age;

public User(String name, String username, String age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.username = username;
    this.age = age;
}
```

Change the return value of doInBackground to `User` and return the User object instead of a string
`return new User(name,username,age);`

**Option 3:**

Return an array or list of strings

```
List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>
data.add(user);
data.add(username);
data.add(age);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass that json string into post execute method and than parse it

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
try{
    URL url = new URL (strUrl);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.connect();

    //get response from server
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String value = bf.readLine();
    return vaue;

}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

    String json = s;
    JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(json);
    JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("Data");
    JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(parentArray.length()-1);

    String name = finalObject.getString("NAME");
    String username = finalObject.getString("USERNAME");
    String age = finalObject.getString("AGE");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

create one model class

```
public class UserDataModel {
    String username,name,age;

public UserDataModel(String username, String name, String age) {
    this.username = username;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(String age) {
    this.age = age;
}
}
```

Now in doInBackground

```
ArrayList<UserDataModel> userList = new ArrayList<>();
protected ArrayList<UserDataModel> doInBackground(String... params) {
try{
URL url = new URL (strUrl);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.connect();

//get response from server
BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
String value = bf.readLine();


String json = value;
JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(json);
JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("Data");
JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(parentArray.length()-1);

UserDataModel model = new UserDataModel();

model.setName= finalObject.getString("NAME");
model.setUsername = finalObject.getString("USERNAME");
model.setAge= finalObject.getString("AGE");

userList.add(model);

return userList;

}catch(Exception e){
   System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: don't post identical answers